# Recursively nested component emitting events to its parent which is an instance of the same component

Tags: javascript, angular

Apologies all I Honestly had no idea how to phrase the question and I understand its not much to go by.

**CONTEXT :**
I have recursively nested 'container' components that are going to be populated with components dynamically for a WYSIWYG HTML editor project I'm busy with.

I need to be able to style a container that is being hovered over differently (border etc.) but due to what seems to be a limitation in the way HTML/CSS works, Hovering on a child element causes the parent to inherently be in a hovered state as well.

I have since been trying to find a programmatic solution.

**GOAL :** I am trying to have the nested container components emit a boolean true to their parent to say that they are hovered over so that the parent sets a property called hovered to false (my styling is based on this value). This means my component is both the emitter and the listener and I thought this would work. It doesn't...

**ISSUE :** The element emitting the event seems to be catching the same event as hovering over a single container component fires the onChildHovered() function. I am probably just misunderstanding how this child parent communication is supposed to work.

**CODE :**

Example Element layout:

```html
    <app-element-container [orientation]="false" type="parent">
        <app-element-container class="row" type="row" >
            <!--etc-->
        </app-element-container>
    </app-element-container>
```

component.ts

```js
import {Component, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-element-container',
  templateUrl: './element-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./element-container.component.scss']
})
export class ElementContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() orientation = true;
  @Input() type = '';

  mouseOver = false;

  @Output() hoverEvent = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  onMouseEnter() {
    this.mouseOver = true;
    this.hoverEvent.emit(true);
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave')
  onMouseLeave() {
    this.mouseOver = false;
  }

  @HostListener('hoverEvent', ['$event'])
  onChildHovered($event) {
    this.mouseOver = $event;
    console.log(this.mouseOver);
  }
}
```

component.html

```html
<div class="element"
     [ngClass]="{'parent': type === 'parent', 'row': type === 'row', 'hover': mouseOver}">
  <div class="element-hover-fix">
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="flag">
        <span>{{type}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="toolbox">
        <div class="button"><md-icon>open_with</md-icon></div>
        <div class="button"><md-icon>content_copy</md-icon></div>
        <div class="button"><md-icon>delete</md-icon></div>
      </div>
      <div class="add-children" [ngClass]="{vertical: !orientation}">
        <div class="add-child">
          <md-icon>chevron_left</md-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="add-child" (click)="orientation = !orientation">
          <md-icon>screen_rotation</md-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="add-child">
          <md-icon>chevron_right</md-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your Example Element layout, the child is not emitting to the parent.
in order to do so, you need to update the layout like so :

```
<app-element-container [orientation]="false" type="parent">
     <app-element-container (hoverEvent)="onChildHoverEvent($event)"
                            class="row" 
                            type="row" >
            <!--etc-->
     </app-element-container>
</app-element-container>
```

Then you will need to declare the onChildHoverEvent to do something when the child is experiencing a mouse over event.

Comment: Does the HostListener annotated method in my component.ts not do the same thing? It is where im listening for the mouseenter and mouse leave events